# Merge Sort C# Invalid Output

Tags: c#, string, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

My homework is about using Strategy Patterns and implementing Bubble sort, Quick sort, and Merge sort. I have done the first two but my Merge Sort seems to be giving me the wrong output when I input "bonakid" it gives me an output of "abkidon". May I know which part is wrong in the implementation?

Also, I have used this particular ISortStrategy on my Bubble Sort and Quick Sort so it would be nice if they would use the same one so I would not have to change the others.

```
 class mergeSort : ISortStrategy
{

    public string Sort(string input)
    {
        var result = "";

        int size = (input.Length % 2 == 0) ? input.Length / 2 : (input.Length + 1) / 2;

        if (input.Length > 1)
        {
            char[] left = input.Substring(0, input.Length / 2).ToCharArray();
            char[] right = input.Substring(input.Length / 2, input.Length - (input.Length / 2)).ToCharArray();

            // Sorting two halves recursively
            Sort(left.Length.ToString());
            Sort(right.Length.ToString());

            //merging left and right sublists
            result = merge(input, left, right);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public string merge(string result, char[] left, char[] right)
    {
        int i1 = 0; // indexing  left
        int i2 = 0; // indexing right

        var theString = result;
        var aStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(theString);

        for (int i = 0; i < aStringBuilder.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i2 >= right.Length || (i1 < left.Length && left.GetValue(i1).ToString().CompareTo(right.GetValue(i2).ToString()) < 0))
            {
                aStringBuilder.Remove(i, 1);
                aStringBuilder.Insert(i, left.GetValue(i1).ToString());
                i1++;
            }
            else
            {
                aStringBuilder.Remove(i, 1);
                aStringBuilder.Insert(i, right.GetValue(i2).ToString());
                i2++;
            }
        }

        theString = aStringBuilder.ToString();
        return theString;

    }
}
```

}

```
 public interface ISortStrategy
{
    string Sort(string input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refined version that minimizes allocations and performs the merge with parallel execution. [Taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371586/how-to-parallelize-a-merge-sort-over-a-spant/73375499#73375499).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ISortStrategy sort = new MergeSort(); 
        Console.WriteLine(sort.Sort("bonakid"));
    }
}

public interface ISortStrategy
{
    string Sort(string input);
}

public class MergeSort : ISortStrategy
{
    public string Sort(string input)
    {
        return SortAlgo.Merge(input).Result;     
    }
}


public static class SortAlgo
{
    public async static ValueTask<string> Merge(
            string input,
            IComparer<char> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer ??= Comparer<char>.Default;
        
        // buffer to contain the orginal data.
        Memory<char> source = new char[input.Length];
        input.AsMemory().CopyTo(source);
        // other buffer, that starts as the output.
        Memory<char> buffer = new char[source.Length];
        
        // copy the stack allocated buffer out as the result;
        return (await MergeLadder(
            source,
            buffer,
            comparer)).ToString();
    }
    
    public async static ValueTask<T[]> Merge<T>(
            T[] input,
            IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer ??= Comparer<T>.Default;
        
        // buffer to contain the orginal data.
        Memory<T> source = new T[input.Length];
        // intentionally copying input so it is not mutated.
        input.AsMemory().CopyTo(source);
        // other buffer, that starts as the output.
        Memory<T> buffer = new T[source.Length];
        
        // copy the stack allocated buffer out as the result;
        return (await MergeLadder(
            source,
            buffer,
            comparer)).ToArray();
    }
    
    /// <remarks>
    /// Bottom up merge with alternatring buffers.
    /// </remarks>
    private async static ValueTask<ReadOnlyMemory<T>> MergeLadder<T>(
        Memory<T> input,
        Memory<T> output,
        IComparer<T> comparer,
        int width = 2)
    {
        var half = width / 2;
        
        await WhenAll(GetMergeTasks(
            input,
            output,
            comparer,
            width,
            half));
        
        // Did the last stride cover the whole input?
        if (width >= input.Length)
        {
            // Yes, everything is sorted
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            // No, walk the array again with double the width.
            // Switch the buffers so we don't walk over the results.
            return await MergeLadder(output, input, comparer, width * 2);
        }
    }
    
    private async static IAsyncEnumerable<Task> GetMergeTasks<T>(
        Memory<T> input,
        Memory<T> output,
        IComparer<T> comparer,
        int width,
        int half)
    {
        // walk the input sequence in mergable strides
        // combine the left and right halves into the output
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += width)
        {
            Memory<T> left;
            Memory<T> right;
            Memory<T> merge;
            
            var remaining = input.Length - i;
            if (remaining <= half)
            {
                // not enough left for a right.
                left = input.Slice(i, remaining);
                right = Memory<T>.Empty;
                merge = output.Slice(i, remaining);
            }
            else if (remaining < width)
            {
                // not enought for a whole right.
                left = input.Slice(i, half);
                right = input.Slice(i + half, remaining - half);
                merge = output.Slice(i, remaining);
            }
            else
            {
                // the full stride.
                left = input.Slice(i, half);
                right = input.Slice(i + half, half);
                merge = output.Slice(i, width);
            }
            
            // Now merge the left and right for this stride.
            yield return Task.Run(() => Merge(left, right, merge, comparer));
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
    
    public static async ValueTask WhenAll(IAsyncEnumerable<Task> tasks)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);

        // We don't allocate the list if no task throws
        List<Exception> exceptions = null;

        await foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                exceptions ??= new();
                exceptions.Add(ex);
            }
        }

        
        if (!(exceptions is null))
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
   }
            
    private static void Merge<T>(
        ReadOnlyMemory<T> leftMemory,
        ReadOnlyMemory<T> rightMemory,
        Memory<T> mergeMemory,
        IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        var left = leftMemory.Span;
        var right = rightMemory.Span;
        var merge = mergeMemory.Span;
        
        //While either span has an element
        for(int m = 0, l = 0, r= 0; l < left.Length || r < right.Length; m++)
        {
            if (l < left.Length && r < right.Length)
            {
                //both sides have elements
                if (comparer.Compare(left[l], right[r]) <= 0)
                {
                    // left is less than right
                    merge[m] = left[l];
                    l++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // right is less than left
                    merge[m] = right[r];
                    r++;
                }
            }
            else if (l < left.Length)
            {
                // only left has some left
                merge[m] = left[l];
                l++;
            }
            else
            {
                // only right has some left
                merge[m] = right[r];
                r++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

As [demonstrated here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CkFzMb), here is a working example,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ISortStrategy mergeSort = new MergeSort();
        Console.WriteLine(mergeSort.Sort("bonakid"));
    }
}

public interface ISortStrategy
{
    string Sort(string input);
}

public class MergeSort : ISortStrategy
{
    public string Sort(string input)
    {
        return new string(Homework.MergeSort(input).ToArray());     
    }
}

public static class Homework
{
    public static IList<T> MergeSort<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> inputSequence,
        IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        }
        
        IList<T> input = inputSequence.ToArray();
        IList<T> left;
        IList<T> right;
        IList<T> result = new T[input.Count];
        
        // As this is a recursive algorithm, we need to have a base case to 
        // avoid an infinite recursion and therfore a stack overflow.
        if (input.Count <= 1)
        {
            return input;
        }
        
        // The exact midpoint of our array.
        int midPoint = Math.DivRem(input.Count, 2, out int twoRemainder);
        
        // Will represent our 'left' array.
        left = new T[midPoint];
  
        
        if (twoRemainder == 0)
        {
            //The array has an even number of elements, the left and right array
            //will have the same number of elements.
            right = new T[midPoint];
        }
        else
        {
            // The array has an odd number of elements, the right array 
            // will have one more element than left.
            right = new T[midPoint + 1];
        }
        
        //populate left array
        for (int i = 0; i < midPoint; i++)
        {
            left[i] = input[i];
        }
        
        // populate right array   
        // start index from the midpoint, as we have already populated
        // the left array from 0 to midpont.
        for (int x = 0, i = midPoint; i < input.Count; i++, x++)
        {
            right[x] = input[i];
        }
        
        //Recursively sort the left array
        left = MergeSort(left);
        
        //Recursively sort the right array
        right = MergeSort(right);
        
        //Merge our two sorted arrays
        result = Merge(left, right, comparer);
        
        return result;
    }
  
    //This method will be responsible for combining our two sorted arrays into one giant array
    private static IList<T> Merge<T>(
        IList<T> left,
        IList<T> right,
        IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int resultLength = right.Count + left.Count;
        IList<T> result = new T[resultLength];
            
        int indexLeft = 0, indexRight = 0, indexResult = 0;
        
        //while either array still has an element
        while (indexLeft < left.Count || indexRight < right.Count)
        {
            // if both arrays have elements  
            if (indexLeft < left.Count && indexRight < right.Count)  
            {  
                // If item on left array is less than item on right array, add that item to the result array 
                if (comparer.Compare(left[indexLeft], right[indexRight]) <= 0)
                {
                    result[indexResult] = left[indexLeft];
                    indexLeft++;
                    indexResult++;
                }
                // else the item in the right array wll be added to the results array
                else
                {
                    result[indexResult] = right[indexRight];
                    indexRight++;
                    indexResult++;
                }
            }
            //if only the left array still has elements, add all its items to the results array
            else if (indexLeft < left.Count)
            {
                result[indexResult] = left[indexLeft];
                indexLeft++;
                indexResult++;
            }
            //if only the right array still has elements, add all its items to the results array
            else if (indexRight < right.Count)
            {
                result[indexResult] = right[indexRight];
                indexRight++;
                indexResult++;
            }  
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: would there be a way on where I can use  public string Sort(string input) as it has been already implemented for my Bubble Sort, and Quick Sort. 
My homework also needs us to use Stategy Design Patterns so i need it to be public string Sort (string input)

Comment: Include the definition of `ISortStrategy` in the question and I'll tweak the answer. Remember a `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: I have included the ISortStrategy in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @blepsters, there are far superior versions of this algorithm that avoid allocation by either yielding the `IEnumerable` or using `Span<T>` .